# How to avoid the duplicate entry of select box option while edit page?

Tags: java, jsp, combobox, jstl

Could anyone please explain me how to avoid the duplicate enters of records in to the select box options during editing the page.I am using java to develop web application I am very new to that,I need to remove the duplicates from the select box option while editing.Could anyone please help me .

**Sample Code**

```
 <td><select property="employeestatus" value="" id="employeestatus"> 
                                                <c:if test="${employee.employeestatus!=null}">
                                                    <option value="${employee.employeestatus}">${employee.employeestatus}</option>
                                                </c:if>
                                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                                <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                                <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
                                                <option value="Deceased">Deceased</option>
                                                <option value="Resigned">Resigned</option>
                                                <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <html:errors property="employeestatus"/>
                                            <p id="employeestatus" style="color:red"/>
                                        </td>
```

Comment: wat u mean by duplicating?u are hardcoding your options..

Comment: I am hardcoding like above code while adding I will select one and store in the database.but editing how to do.that i was appeding in the top.remaining are there in below.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add the **selected** attribute on the option corresponding to your "employeestatus" variable instead of duplicating this option on the first line.

See [HTML option selected Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

By the `<html:errors ...>`, I gess you use Struts 1. If it's true, I would use the

`<html:select ...>` tag and

`<html:options or optionsCollection ...>`

with java Map store in some context **(servlet, session or request)** to configure options. That struts tag will select the good option corresponding to your variable value.

See [Struts `<html:select ...>` doc](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#select)

Comment: could u just expline for my above example.

Comment: `<html:select property="employeestatus">
    <html:option value="">Select</html:option>
    <html:options property="employeeStatusMap or List" />
</html:select>`